# math program for addition multiplication in c++

Tags: c++, math

```
void additionmenu()
{
    char choice;
    printf("Please select the level");
    printf("A level 1");
    printf("B level 2");
    printf("C level 3");
    scanf("%c", &choice);
    if (choice == "A" || "a")
    {
        printf("You have selected level 1\n");
        additionmenu();
    }
    else if (choice == "B" || "b")
    {
        printf("You have selected level 2\n");
        subtractionmenu();
    }
    else if (choice == "C" || "c")
    {
        printf("You have selected level 3\n");
        multiplicationmenu();
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid choice\n");

    }
```

error occur at line 58,63,68,84,96

```
'==': 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'char [2]'
 'time' undefined; assuming extern returning int    
illegal else without matching if
```

those are the error...

can some one hlp me to slove 
i have to develop a math quiz program 
n can someone tell me how to create a sub fuction for level1,2,3

Comment: ignore those line error...its just '==': 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'char [2]' this one

Comment: Your comparisons are not doing what you think they are. Rather than `choice == "A" || "a"` you should have `choice == 'A' || choice == 'a'`

Comment: `choice == 'A' || choice == 'a'`